# Can Active Directory B2C use the Native Facebook App instead of webview?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, azure-ad-b2c

We built two native apps (1 Android and 1 iOS) that use AADB2C. When users need to login/register, they go through a series of AADB2C webviews. We also enabled social login through Facebook by configuring a Facebook App in AADB2C. This works, as in, users can login with Facebook, but this is also done in the webview, meaning they need to type login and password explicitly here.

**Is there some way to leverage the native Facebook Login?** This would make logging in and registering a lot more user-friendly?

By the way: Firebase Auth achieved this by triggering the Facebook App from the webview - so it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROPC flow with AD B2C to achieve the same.

The resource owner password credentials (ROPC) flow is an OAuth standard authentication flow where the application, also known as the relying party, exchanges valid credentials such as userid and password for an ID token, access token, and a refresh token.

[image]

Here is the announcement for the same:

https://twitter.com/codemillmatt/status/994927109503160320?s=21

In Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C, the following options are supported:

- **Native Client**: User interaction during authentication happens when code runs on a user-side device. The device can be a mobile application that's running in a native operating system, such as Android, or running in a browser, such as JavaScript.
- **Public client flow**: Only user credentials, gathered by an application, are sent in the API call. The credentials of the application are not sent.
- **Add new claims**: The ID token contents can be changed to add new claims.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc#implement-with-your-preferred-native-sdk-or-use-app-auth

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will check this answer out but meanwhile would still like to see if this is possible without ROPC, because ROPC introduces other issues. Thank you.